# sed group out of string and put it into variable

Tags: variables, sed

Can you make it work?

```
result=${docker ps | sed -r 's/(.*)\s.*$/\1/'} && echo $result
```

Just want to pass the result of the seed into a variable (and print it out for debugging)
The tricky thing is, that docker ps returns multiple lines!

Update:

I changed It due to an post farther down to

```
result=$(docker ps | sed -r 's/(.*)\s.*$/\1/'} && echo "$result"
```

But this is the result:

```
root@Synobaby916:/volume1/Synology-Infrastructure/sys_scripts# result=$(docker ps | sed -r 's/(.*)\s.*$/\1/'} && echo "$result"
>
```

Behind the > is just a blinking cursor ...

Comment: How can we possibly help when you show no input or output or any errors?  You do use the wrong brackets for the process substitution, so it should be $() and not ${}.  I would add that the && is kind of pointless as there will never be an error assigning a value to result, even if it is empty

Answer (score 0):

To expand a variable it should be enclosed with double quotes `"$result"` or embraced with `{}` `${result}`:

```
result=$(docker ps | sed -r 's/(.)\s.$/\1/') && echo "$result"
```

Here's a simplified analogy:

```
result=$(echo "hello there" | sed -rn 's/^([a-z]).*/\1/p') && echo "$result"
```

It'll output:
`h` (the first character of the string)

Comment: when I do that -> result=$(docker ps | sed -r 's/(.*)\s.*$/\1/'} && echo "$result" -> I just get an > and a blinking cursor

Comment: sorry, copy and paste problem...wanted to make a linebreak and don´t know how :-)